# Toshiba Satellite L75D-A7280 BIOS doesn't ask for set administrative password

Tags: bios, passwords, administrator, toshiba-laptop

I've set my administrative password.  I have not set a user password.

When I get into the BIOS, everything is greyed, and there's no where to put in the password.

How do I enter the password to administer my BIOS?

**BIOS**

Insyde20.

This is a [manual](ftp://ftp.packardbell.com/pub/itemnr/6917490001/BIOS_Insyde_gharial_01.pdf).  I think I may have been given the option to set "Verify password when..." to "Never" and stupidly did it after they stupidly gave the option.

Comment: Have you tried just entering your password and pressing Enter?

Comment: @Yassar yes but will try again without touching anything first, and there is absolutely no prompt and nothing in the f1 help.

Comment: That's strange. You could try randomly hitting each F key in turn and see what happens

Comment: @Yassar tried that too.  retried touching nothing, entering password & [Enter].  no go.  editing...

Comment: Have you tried a BIOS update or reverting to an older BIOS version?

Comment: @Yassar I installed the only one available on their site, lol.  I only recently put on the admin pass, not while it had the previous version.  Will check again for new version...

Comment: Oh, lol. Would it be possible to clear CMOS?

Comment: @Yassar Think so.  Saw a lot of q&a's elsewhere that showed how to do it with older Tosh-Sats.  Want to see if there's an easy way out before going nuclear.  Think it may have given option to set "Verify password when..." to "Never", and I may have stupidly set it that way.  :(  will put manual in edit...

Comment: How would the BIOS know you're entering the correct password if it doesn't verify it? I wouldn't have though such as option exists. It's most likely an issue with the BIOS version imo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Unplug the power & remove the battery.
2. Hold the power button for 30 seconds.
3. Attach battery and plugin power cable.
4. Hold F2
5. Power on laptop

Supervisor password prompt should appear.

---

Pressing F11 while at the password prompt will prevent the BIOS from demanding the password and allow the user to view the BIOS in limited mode.